# Celery tasks taking longer to run process than if using without celery

Tags: python, celery, plotly-dash

I am using celery to handle a function that sometimes can take a long time to process due to using a networkx graph to find all paths (specifically the [all_simple_paths](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.all_simple_paths.html) method).

Before using celery there were some simulations that took 1-30s so this was fine for nginx not to timeout, however then there were others that could be anything between 30s - 2m.

I opted to use celery and and poll the status until completed, this all works fine, however now the simulations that were originally taking between 1-30s now can take up 2m. I understand that the broker/backend adds some overhead, but surely not this much? Is there a way to get these simulations running at normal performance?

I built the poller using dash, I did it with two different versions as I was using dash v1 at first.

*dash v1 ex*

```
@app.callback(
    Output("analysis-button", "disabled"),
    Output("analysis-button", "children"),
    Output("cancel-button", "disabled"),
    Output("future-content", "data"),
    Output("result-tuple", "data"),
    Output("poller", "max_intervals"),
    Input("analysis-button", "n_clicks"),
    State("param", "value"),
    State("param_one", "value"),
    State("param_two", "value"),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def start_celery_process(
    n_clicks: bool,
    param: str,
    param_one: str,
    param_two: str
):
    logger.info("Button pressed")
    content_for_polling = short_paths(param, param_one, param_two)
    cel_status = find_all_paths.delay(param, param_one, param_two) # this can take a long time or short time
    return True, "Analyzing...", False, content_for_polling, cel_status.as_tuple(), -1

@app.callback(
    [
        Output("analysis-button", "disabled"),
        Output("analysis-button", "children"),
        Output("cancel-button", "disabled"),
        Output("ret-one", "data"),
        Output("ret-two", "data"),
        Output("ret-three", "data"),
        Output("poller", "max_intervals"),
    ],
    [Input("poller", "n_intervals"), Input("future-content", "data")],
    [State("result-tuple", "data")],
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def poll_result(n_intervals, future_content, data):
    logger.info("in poll")
    result = result_from_tuple(data, app=celery_app)
    logger.info(result)
    if not result.ready():
        logger.info("prevented updated poll")
        raise PreventUpdate()
    logger.info("gets into update")
    para_fut, para_fut_one, para_fut_two = future_content
    param_res, param_res_one, param_res_two = result.get()
    ret_param = para_fut.append(para_fut)
    ret_param_one = para_fut_two.append(para_fut_one)
    ret_param_two = para_fut_two.append(para_fut_two)
    
    return (
        False,
        "Analyze",
        True,
        ret_param,
        ret_param_one,
        ret_param_two,
        0
    )
```

I then saw that dash in v2 has a [long callback](https://dash.plotly.com/long-callbacks) which integrates celery into it, so I updated my version and tried to implement that but still have the same issue.

```
celery_app = Celery(__name__, broker="redis://localhost:6379/0"),
                    backend="redis://localhost:6379/1"))
long_callback_manager = CeleryLongCallbackManager(celery_app)


@app.long_callback(
    Output("analysis-button", "disabled"),
    Output("analysis-button", "children"),
    Output("cancel-button", "disabled"),
    Output("ret-one", "data"),
    Output("ret-two", "data"),
    Output("ret-three", "data"),
    Input("analysis-button", "n_clicks"),
    State("param", "value"),
    State("param_one", "value"),
    State("param_two", "value"),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
    manager=long_callback_manager
)
def start_celery_process(
    n_clicks: bool,
    param: str,
    param_one: str,
    param_two: str
):
    logger.info("Button pressed")
    para_fut, para_fut_one, para_fut_two = short_paths(param, param_one, param_two)
    param_res, param_res_one, param_res_two = find_all_paths(param, param_one, param_two) # this can take a long time or short time
    ret_param = para_fut.append(para_fut)
    ret_param_one = para_fut_two.append(para_fut_one)
    ret_param_two = para_fut_two.append(para_fut_two)
    
    return (
        False,
        "Analyze",
        True,
        ret_param,
        ret_param_one,
        ret_param_two,
    )
```

Just as writing this, my thoughts are now is that it takes a long time due to the pickle serializer as I had the config like so:

```
celery_app.conf.task_serializer = 'pickle'
celery_app.conf.result_serializer = 'pickle'
celery_app.conf.accept_content = ['application/json', 'application/x-python-serialize']
```

But I removed that and it did not do anything.

The `find_all_paths` method looks like:

```
def find_all_paths(
        source_ID,
        target_ID,
        min_path,
):
    logger.info("starts find all paths")
    source = index_a[source_ID]
    target = index_a[target_ID]
    start = time.time()
    for path in nx.all_simple_paths(G, source, target, 60): # where G is the network x graph
        paths, paths_weights, weights_map = transform_path(source, target, inv_index_a) 

        elapsed = time.time() - start
        if elapsed > limit:
            break

    return (
        paths,
        paths_weights,
        weights_map,

    )
```

UPDATE:

I ran a `sys.getsizeof` to get the size of each object being returned in bytes like so:

```
sys.getsizeof(my_obj))
```

and the values for each of the three return objects was:

```
336
336
360
```

This was done with the version 2 `long_callback` with the data that is to be returned. This particular simulation takes 30s without celery and works fine on nginx server. With the long callback (celery implementation) it takes just over 1 minute.

Comment: How large is your data? Unless it is really large, the overhead added by celery should be negligible

Comment: @emher Just added sizes.

Comment: Could it be simply that you are running too many tasks in parallel? If the underlying hardware has, say 8 CPU cores, but you run Celery worker with (say prefork) concurrency set to 16, then it is quite possible that all the tasks run slower, because they use less than 100% of the CPU core. I always run Celery worker with concurrency set to N where `N = number-of-cores - 1` (for CPU-bound tasks).